# 3d Fenwick tree

Tags: algorithm, 3d, tree, fenwick-tree

I have a three-dimensional [fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) data structure.
I need to calculate sum on some segment from `(x0, y0, z0)` to `(x, y, z)`

What is the formula for inclusion-exclusion?
For instance, for 2D variant it is

```
s = sum(x, y) - sum(x, y0 - 1) - sum(x0 - 1, y) + sum(x0 - 1, y0 - 1)
```

Thanks in advance

http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/ft.pdf

Here is 2D case: 
[image]

Comment: Please provide either a reference (link) or a good explanation of what a 3-D Fenwick Tree it.

Comment: I've just solved my problem. Anyway, maybe, someone will stuck with this too, so:long s = sum(x, y, z)-sum(x0 - 1, y, z) - sum(x, y0 - 1, z) - sum(x, y, z0 - 1) - sum(x0 - 1, y0 - 1, z0 - 1) + sum(x0 - 1, y0 - 1, z) + sum(x0 - 1, y, z0 - 1) + sum(x, y0 - 1, z0 - 1)

Comment: @DenysAstanin : If you find the solution to your own problem , come back and add that as a solution and accept it too so that others can know and if someone has the same issue , it can help them too.

Answer (score 6):

formula involves total 8 computations

```
value1 = sum(x,y,z)- sum(x0-1,y,z)  - sum(x,y0-1,z) + sum(x0-1,y0-1,z)

value2 = sum(x,y,z0-1) - sum(x0-1,y,z0-1) - sum(x,y0-1,z0-1)  + sum(x0-1,y0-1,z0-1)


final answer = value1 - value2
```

Time complexity of code is `8 (logn)^3`

**How can you visualize.**

```
1> assume it as a cube.

2> value 1 gives answer for upper square layer of cube, but it include sum upto 0 in z-axis. 

You only want upto z0, so you have subtract that extra part(from z0 to 0, and that is value2).
```